# failed to extract data from json with jq command

Tags: json, jq

I've this json.
I want to extract test fields which their values equal to true.
I tried with jq and got that error, pls any fix ?

```
$- jq '.[].name | select(.[].test == "true")' ddd                                                                                  

jq: error (at ddd:12): Cannot iterate over string ("AA")
```

```
[
{
"name": "AA",
"program_url": "https://www.google.com",
"test": false
},
{
"name": "BB",
"program_url": "https://yahoo.com",
"test": true
}
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What output are you expecting?  Please follow the guidelines for asking questions: [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this? It iterates over the array `.[]`, `select`s those item objects whose `.test` field evaluates to `true` (implicit), and traverses further down to the `.name` field. Using the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) option renders the output raw text (instead of JSON string in this case).

```bash
jq -r '.[] | select(.test).name' ddd
```

```json
BB
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yOSSY6BTlKI)